# Virtuemart $variables. Where can I learn / output them?

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

Within Virtuemart, i'm referencing such things like

```
 $this->product->images[0]->file_url;
```

and

```
 $category->category_name;
```

With little documentation, is there some technique that I can find what variable references are available to me? How do I know if I can access, say `$this->product->product_title`. How do I get these out of VM, with no documentation?

Short of best guessing what do developers do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

> `print_r($this->product);exit();`

Then check the source code of the page

Comment: Yeah check the source code to display it properly. Displayed is all the content of $product variable. Then you call what you need...

Comment: Your right, Julien.. althought i'd prefer some documentation... :)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is limited, here it is:

http://virtuemart.net/documentation/Developer_Manual/func.html